# finding not exactly same template in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to find a character in my input image. When I crop char from an image and use template matching, in almost all cases, it works perfect; but if I use that template for another image with a little different shape of char it fails.

This is my question: How can I find object in my images similar to my template but with a little variety in slope or line thickness or ... ? Is there any way with template matching or do you suggest another methods according to your experience?

I will appreciate any related answer in advance.

Comment: Template matching looks for exact matches in the image. If you have even the slightest of variations (shading, illumination, etc.) you won't get the match you expect. In order to continue using template matching you can first pre-process the images such that they look similar

Comment: Dear @JeruLuke, thank you for your comment. That's right. I tried some preprocessing techniques to achieve better results but due to different background (and in some cases complex background images) I've could not find a good preprocessed version that fit my template so far. I think I should forget about template matching and look for alternative (more robust) methods. I should work on Arthur's suggestions (in answers). Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are facing a limitation of template matching here. It seems like you are already using the right metric (normalised cross-correlation). Maybe one last thing you can do is to check for 5 templates: a 'perfect' one (take from a perfect image) and 4 rotated versions. Then, for each template you find the best match, and then compare the 5 best matches against each other to pick the best of them.

Depending on how much time you want to invest, and what robustness level you wish to accomplish, you can also use Neural Network ! It will b the more robust approach to this problem. Of course, there are some neural network trained for character detection, for instance [here](https://github.com/argman/EAST), and some available tutorial [like this one](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/).

If you don't want to use NN, you could think of another method which could work with line detection. A '/' character has a quite characteristic shape: a closed path, rotated with a certain angle, with 'inertia' around one single axis. That is easy to describe with some mathematical properties of the detected closed shape. This approach is called *shape descriptor* and is described (for instance) [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/12827668.pdf). I think that if you have some knowledge on the size of the text, and pretty good image quality, then this 'low-level' approach has some potential. It often works really well.

I hope this helps you to solve your problem.